# Get URL parameters using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am using states to go from page to page. From one of URLs I am reading parameter from URL (id) and I can easily do this when defining state.

```
.config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state("testing", {
                url: "/testSession/:id",
                controller: "UserTestSessionController",
                templateUrl: "./app/components/userTestSession/user-test-session.html",
                controllerAs: "vm"
            })
    })
```

My URL looked like this: `localhost:8000\testSession\id`

If I change URL to look like this: `localhost:8000\testSession\id?otp="someStringValue"` can I somehow define otp in url param of state? Or do I need to change it totally?

Comment: Do you need otp to be in URL ? can't you use `$location` to get the query string ?

Comment: @sajan Well it would be easier to define it in URL if it's even possible. If not I can always use $location, I agree on that. Just wanted to check is there a way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add `?opt` to the `url`

If you need to have more than one, separate them with an '&'

```
.config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state("testing", {
                url: "/testSession/:id?otp",
                controller: "UserTestSessionController",
                templateUrl: "./app/components/userTestSession/user-test-session.html",
                controllerAs: "vm"
            })
    })
```

Comment: Just one more question. How will I get otp later from Controller for example? Do I use $location, or there is a better way to do it. Because for now I get that ID=1&OTPVALUE. @Weedoze

Comment: Use `$stateParam.opt`

Comment: I did, but it's get Id=1&otpvalue and otp = undefine. Let me update my question and add code from Controller. Maybe you will see where is the mistake... @Weedoze

Comment: You should ask another question. Your first question was answered. Try to find yourself the solution, if you cannot find come back with another question

Comment: I just asked new question. Thanks :) @Weedoze